# Akka correlate query and response

Tags: scala, akka

I have an actor which receive a message  ->
(title - title of the item, maxAmount - how much he could pay for it)

```
case Bid(title, maxAmount) => {
  val search = ...
  search ! Auction.Find(title)
}
```

then this actor send find message to check wheter given auction is available. If so, it receives the following message

```
case Auction.Result(list) => {
  for(auction <- list) {
    auction ! Auction.Bid(maxAmount)
  }
}
```

And the problem is that this maxAmount isn't available in this case section. How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first solution that pops into mind may be maintaining the `maxAmount` as state in your actor code between messages. This is quite dangerous, because then you also need to find a way to find out which `Result` belongs to which `Find` message. I suggest you add the information to the `Find` message:

```
case class Find(bid: Bid)
```

so that your `search` actor can return it in the `Result` message:

```
case Result(maxAmount: Double, list: List[SomeResultType])
```

or you could use the actor [ask pattern](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-akka-actors-ask-examples-future-await-timeout-result):

```
import akka.pattern.ask
case Bid(title, maxAmount) => {
  val search = ...
  val res: Auction.Result = search ? Auction.Find(title)
  res.list.foreach(_ ! Auction.Bid(maxAmount))
}
```

in order for this to work, your `search` actor must reply to `sender()` like this:

```
case Auction.Find(title) =>
  val res: Result = find(title)
  sender() ! res
```